# Track android listview run time errors

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way to track the errors while populating a list view from an adapter?
I mean If one item failed to load to list view is there any way to find it?

Comment: I mean if an item is not loaded into the list for some resons.Is it possible to find it

Comment: In my app I have listed installed apps using PackageManager getInstalledPackages();But some apps are not listed.I don't know the reason for this.

Comment: start by catching exceptions and logging errors

Answer (score 0):

if your adapter is custom you can set Log in getView method which will give you logs as per your requirement of in some condition when object is null.